# Problems with LaTeX in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I'm relatively new to working with Jupiter Notebook. So I apologise if this is a stupide question. But I got this Notebook and it seems like the there is a problem with displaying LaTeX. It the first case I have:

```
Original 1-D Schrodinger equation: $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi + V \psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi$

=> $\text{psi_t} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t,x) = -i\left[-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(t,x) + \frac{1}{\hbar} V(x) \psi(t,x)\right]$
```

and I get this error:

[image: error 1]

I found out by now that the `_t` in `\text{psi_t}` seems to be the problem here. Without it not error appears.

I also have a problem here:

```
## Laplace Operator (Finite Difference)

The 1-D Laplace operator $\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ can be expressed in terms of a banded matrix:
$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} y(x)
&= 
\frac{1}{dx} \left[ \frac{y_{n+1} - y_{n}}{dx} - \frac{y_{n} - y_{n-1}}{dx} \right]
\\
&=
\frac{y_{n+1} - 2 y_{n} + y_{n-1}}{(dx)^2} 
\\
&=
\frac{1}{(dx)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
  -2  &  1  &  0  &  0 &  0 \\
   1  & -2  &  1  &  0 &  0 \\
   0  &  1  & -2  &  1 &  0 \\
   0  &  0  &  1  & -2 &  1 \\
   0  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
   y_1   \\
   y_2   \\
   y_3   \\
   y_4   \\
   y_5   
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&\equiv
\mathbf{D2} \cdot \mathbf{y}
\end{align}
$
```

I get this error:
[image: error 2]

I'm using VSCode and win10

Comment: Like the name `\text` might suggest: the content of `\text{...}` is in text mode. You must not use math commands like `_` there

Comment: The `align` environment already puts the content in math mode, don't surround it by inline math `$...$`

Comment: Thank you very much. Removing the ```\text``` worked. But removing the ```$...$``` did not change anything. Do you have any other idea what the problem could be?